# My first Bash script does not look so efficient

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, automation, suse

This is my first bash script using some resources I found online. I think there is a better way to write this perhaps using some other form of conditionals (if then vs control operators).

It is a script that basically checks if a host is up or down (check if it is ping-able). You dump all the ip addresses you want into a file, then run the script calling on the file. The text file looks like this:

```
8.8.8.8                                                                                                             
4.8.8.8                                                                                                             
4.4.4.4                                                                                                             
127.0.0.1
```

The actual script looks like this. Is the 2>&1 necessary because it worked without. I had to play around with the brackets a lot.

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                         

while read line                                                                                                     
do                                                                                                                  
A=$(ping -c 1 $line)                                                                                                
((echo $A | grep "64 bytes") > /dev/null 2>&1 && (echo "UP - "$line)) || echo "DOWN - "$line                        
done < $1
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it entirely without brackets:

```
while read -r address; do
  ping -c 1 $address >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo "UP - $address" || echo "DOWN - $address"
done < file
```

The `>/dev/null 2>&1` redirects both STDOUT and STDERR to `/dev/null` meaning that whatever `ping` outputs won't be printed to your terminal.

You can then use the `&&` and `||` operators to echo a message in case of success (ping exits with `0`) or failure (ping exits with `>0`)

You could use if..then..else if you prefer:

```
while read -r address; do
  if ping -c 1 $address > /dev/null 2>&1; then 
    echo "UP - $address"
  else 
    echo "DOWN - $address"
  fi
done < file
```

Comment: thank you :) I tried to upvote you but I don't have enough reputation or something

Answer (score 1):

arco444 has the right answer. Some other notes

- with the form `A && B || C`, if A succeeds then B executes; if B fails, C will execute. That will not occur for `if A; then B; else C; fi`
- proper indentation is extremely helpful to identify errors (none here, but in general)
- Use better variable names: `$ip` is more meaningful than `$line`
- variables go *inside* the quotes
- parentheses introduce subshells, which will reduce performance. Use only when necessary

Comment: thanks Glenn this was very helpful i am going to make these adjustments now.

Comment: your first point - what would occur then for if A;then B;else C;fi?

Comment: If A succeeds, C will **not** be executed regardless of the exit status of B.

Comment: When B and C are simple commands like `echo`, there's usually no worry with A&&B||C: echo is highly unlike to ever fail. For more complicated things, this difference in behaviour is something to keep in mind.

Comment: thanks very much. any books you can recommend me on bash? thanks.. :D

Comment: No, but I refer constantly to the GNU bash manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html -- it's very dense, but carefully reading it top-down will be educational. Feel free to ask questions here on stackoverflow: I have learned so much from the experts here.

Comment: @2legit2quit I found this very helpful when I was starting with bash: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/